# Customer Attributes in custom tab in Manage Customer in admin

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, customer, custom, custom-attributes

I am new to Magento. I want a solution for how to add custom attributes to custom tab in manage customer.

How is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

Use below Urls for create the new custom attribut in manage customer.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manage-customer-attributes-1.html

and

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/manage-category-customer-and-customer-address-attributes.html

Comment: Hello @sumil. Thanks for you reply I already created Custom Attribute But I want in Custom Tab